# Puppet module to manage groups not working

Tags: puppet, groups

I have configured a module to set up a new group using the following documentation: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/group.html.

```
[root@puppetmaster ~]# cat /etc/puppet/modules/change-groups/manifests/init.pp 
class change-groups {

    group { "newgroup":
        gid => 3651,
        members => "user1,user2",
    }

}
```

Unfortunately I do get an error message. What could be the reason?

```
info: /Group[newgroup]: Provider groupadd does not support features manages_members; not managing attribute members
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/group.htm):

> Manage groups. On most platforms this can only create groups. **Group
>   membership must be managed on individual users**.
>
> On some platforms such as OS X, group membership is managed as an
>   attribute of the group, not the user record. Providers must have the
>   feature ‘manages_members’ to manage the ‘members’ property of a group
>   record

This is [notoriously](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1298) not working on Linux platforms that use groupadd/groupmod/groupdel to edit groups - see [upstream issue #1298](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1298).

There is an [alternative group provider](https://github.com/pdxcat/puppet-module-group) by the Portland State University that can edit the group file.

Another option is to use Augeas to manage the group file.

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.4

Comment: Clearly the log says that "Provider groupadd does not support features manages_members" so under EL what you want to do do not seem possible.

Answer (score 2):

Default group providers in Puppet distribution don't include one able to manage group memberships. However, someone at Portland State University has required the same functionality and coded [some custom provider(s)](https://github.com/pdxcat/puppet-module-group). What you need from this is the file `ggroupadd.pp` which you'd like to put in `/etc/puppet/modules/custom/lib/puppet/provider/group` (adjust appropriately to reflect the location of your custom modules directory).

The new ggroupadd provider will manage groups so that whatever you put in member attribute will get into the file `/etc/group` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the puppet maintainers never provided support for it. I'm looking at the groupadd functionality in the Ruby libraries, and it seems to be a combination of sloppy code and/or incomplete code.